# How to find all words with x (and one or more) occurrences of a letter?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an answer to my second question right here:
To find words with one or more occurrences of the letter 'a' in it

```
var re = /(\w+a)/;
```

With regards to the above, how does it work? For example,

```
var re = /(\w+a)/g;
var str = "gamma";
console.log(re.exec(str));
```

Output:

```
[ 'gamma', 'gamma', index: 0, input: 'gamma' ]
```

However; these are not the results I expected (although it IS what I want). That is to say, re should have found patterns such that there were any number of occurrences of \w. Then the first occurrence of the letter 'a'. Then stop.
I.e. I expected: ga.
Then mma

Next, how do I look for words with a pre-defined number of occurrences (call it x) of the letter 'a'. Such that f(x)=gamma iff x=2.

Comment: That regex will return `false` for `/(\w+a)/.test("abc")`.

Comment: Curious...explanation for why? I thought they were "greedy."

Comment: Never mind, It was in beuttener's answer. Sort of. The * v.s. the +. It is looking for 1+ occurrence of any letter (taking the 'a' as a result) and then looking for 'a'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Repetition in regex is [greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy). That is it takes as much as possible. You happen to get the full word, because it ends in an `a`. To make it ungreedy, (stop at the first one), you'd use:

```
\w+?a
```

But to actually get the full word, I'd rather use

```
\w*a\w*
```

Note the `*`, otherwise you'll get problems with words that have an `a` only as the first or last letter.

To get words with *exactly* 2 `a` you need to exclude `a` from the repeated letters. This is best done with a negated character class, that disallows non-word characters and `a`s. In addition you need to make sure, that you get full words. This is easily done with the word boundary `\b`:

```
\b[^\Wa]*a[^\Wa]*a[^\Wa]*\b
```

For more flexibility in terms of the number of repetitions, this can be rewritten as

```
\b[^\Wa]*(?:a[^\Wa]*){2}\b
```

Comment: You are right. I used a silly example. "gammam" does not yield the full word.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are greedy by default.  That means that if they can grab more characters they will.  You need to consider greed when using quantifiers, like + and *.

To make a quantifier not greedy (lazy) suffix it with a `?`.

```
/(\w+?a)/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex for something, such as

```
/\b\w*a\w*\b/ - find a word with at least 1 a (can match the word 'a')
/\b\w*(?:a\w*){2}\b/ - find a word with at least 2 as
```

But it gets tricky when the amount is exact, because you must change the `\w` to include all letters except `a`... works by the negated class, thus

```
/\b[^\Wa]*(?:a[^\Wa]*){2}\b/ - matches a word with exactly 2 as
```

To find the syllables or so until the "a" letter, then you can use

```
/\b(?:[^\Wa]*a)/ - matches ga alone and in gamma

/\b(?:[^\Wa]*a){1,4}/ - matches word having 1-4 a, ending in a.
```

The easiest way to achieve something like this is however is to match all words /\w+/, and filter them by Javascript.